# How do Install Microsoft Fakes (Unit Test Isolation) on VS 2013 Professional edition

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-fakes

I want to start writing unit test cases using the Microsoft Fakes framework in Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Please advise on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fakes is only available with VS Ultimate and Premium. There is no installer that will allow you add the fakes functionality to VSPro

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs

Comment: I have used MOQ, RhinoMocks, TypeMock Isolator, and Fakes.  I believe Fakes and TypeMock Isolator are the only mocking frameworks that allow "Detours" where a dependency in the code-under-test in unavoidable.  But I find 99.9% of the time any other mocking framework will suffice.  As a result of MS restricting use of 'Fakes' with the most expensive version of VS has caused me to become proficient in RhinoMocks, and now I prefer it over MS Fakes.  The strategy of including a mocking framework with the most expensive VS version is likely to bite back in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Although Fakes is only available to VS Ultimate/Enterprise users, its predecessor, [Moles](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/moles-isolation-framework-for-net/), is available for free.

They're [largely the same](https://davefancher.com/2012/06/14/moles-vs-fakes-the-differences/), except Fakes uses a different naming scheme, and plays slightly better with non-MSTest testing frameworks.

There is also an open-source alternative named [Prig](http://urasandesu.github.io/Prig/) which I know nothing about.